# Scraping next page of same link using python scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I want to scrape (all the titles of) next page of the link: https://www.thetoptens.com/animals/ by clocking on next button using scrapy-selenium, but it scrapes the 1st page of the link.
I have also tried using webdriver but shows same result.

Code using scrapy-selenium:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
class MovieSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "movies"
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
        url='https://www.thetoptens.com/animals/',
        callback=self.parse,
        wait_time=3,
        wait_until=EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pages']/a[@class='g' and text()=9]"))
            )
    def parse(self, response):
        main_category = response.xpath("//div[@class='listgrid']/a/text()").getall()
        yield {
        "main": main_category}
```

Code using webdriver(selenium):

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
class MovieSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "movies"
    start_urls = ["https://www.thetoptens.com/animals/"]
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\python\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(self.start_urls[0])
        #next_page = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pages']/a[@class='g' and text()=9]")
        next_page = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pages']/a[text()=2]")
        if next_page:
            next_page.click()
            a = response.xpath("//div[@class='listgrid']/a/text()").getall()
            yield {
                "aaa": a
                 }
        self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is run sequentially and you are not iterating over the potential number of pages available, just add a while loop until it finds no more 'next' a tags.

```py
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
class MovieSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "movies"
    start_urls = ["https://www.thetoptens.com/animals/"]
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\python\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
    def parse(self, response):
        nextFlag = True
        self.driver.get(self.start_urls[0])
        while nextFlag:
            next_page = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pages']/a[@class='g' and text()=9]")
            if next_page:
                a = response.xpath("//div[@class='listgrid']/a/text()").getall()
                yield {
                    "aaa": a
                 }
                next_page.click()
            else:
                nextFlag = False
        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: It worked using time sleep, but it scrapes the 1st page data of all pages rather than each pages's own data

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use the urls of the ajax requests. To locate them use the inspector of your browser, in its network tab:

```
https://www.thetoptens.com/ajaxcategory.asp?p=1&c=16&sc=&ssc=&n=1367&sort=&type=
https://www.thetoptens.com/ajaxcategory.asp?p=2&c=16&sc=&ssc=&n=1367&sort=&type=
https://www.thetoptens.com/ajaxcategory.asp?p=3&c=16&sc=&ssc=&n=1367&sort=&type=
```

....

Documentation:

[Using your browser’s Developer Tools for scraping in Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html)